# django "static" tag doesn't work with svg

Tags: html, django, svg

I am using an SVG with a href of

```
/static/portfolios/trillio/img/sprite.svg#icon-chat
```

that works just fine but when I use:

```
{% static 'portfolios/trillio/img/sprite.svg#icon-chat' %}
```

the SVG doesnt' show, but the browser console doesn't show any error, the output for the static is this:

```
/static/portfolios/trillio/img/sprite.svg%23icon-chat
```

is it the `%23` that's making a difference and if so how do I fix that?

Comment: The `#` gets escaped, you can work with `{% static 'portfolios/trillio/img/sprite.svg' %}#icon-chat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the '#' is getting converted to a URL code.

So you can instead put the `#icon-chat` **outside** of the code block.

**Like this:** `{% static 'portfolios/trillio/img/sprite.svg' %}#icon-chat`